# how to access array in array when inserting json data to database?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have json file that contains of 50 lines of similar

`"results":[{"score":0,"team_id":126266},{"score":0,"team_id":125798}]`.

I need to insert this to database, but I keep getting errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: results[0]:score[0] in D:\xampp\htdocs\json\index.php on line 26
>
> Notice: Undefined index: results[1]:score[0] in D:\xampp\htdocs\json\index.php on line 27
>
> Notice: Undefined index: results[0]:team_id[0] in D:\xampp\htdocs\json\index.php on line 32
>
> Notice: Undefined index: results[1]:team_id[0] in D:\xampp\htdocs\json\index.php on line 33

Here's the code:

```
$pirmo_oponento_rezultatas = $row['results[0]:score[0]'];
$antro_oponento_rezultatas = $row['results[1]:score[0]'];    
$fk_Komandosid_Komandos = $row['results[0]:team_id[0]'];
$fk_Komandosid_Komandos1 = $row['results[1]:team_id[0]'];

$sql="INSERT INTO rungtynes (pirmo_oponento_rezultatas,antro_oponento_rezultatas,fk_Komandosid_Komandos,
fk_Komandosid_Komandos1) VALUES ('$pirmo_oponento_rezultatas','$antro_oponento_rezultatas',
'$fk_Komandosid_Komandos','$fk_Komandosid_Komandos1')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access as below

```
$pirmo_oponento_rezultatas = $row['results'][0]['score']; 
$antro_oponento_rezultatas = $row['results'][1]['score'];
```